# A wrongly 'I need help' text was sent from google maps

Tags: android-device-manager

I left my phone where I work and I needed a #. I asked a coworker to gain access. An 'I need help' text alert was sent to one of my groups and I recieved the same message from one of them. It was sent 20 minutes before it was discovered. Upon frantically calling to find out what kind of help was needed, I found that it was bogus. It was unnerving, to say the least. Aside from shutting it off, what can be done to correct this?

Comment: Don't let your co-workers, or anyone else, unlock or even gain physical access to your phone is the solution. Otherwise I am not sure exactly what you are asking... What is it you want to correct?

Comment: From [this blog](https://felicecohen.wordpress.com/2017/05/11/s-o-s-sending-out-scary-texts/) and [this question on Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/184391/59741), looks like an emergency/panic feature on some Android phones by pressing the home/power button 3 times. However, I don't know if it can be disabled or not.

Comment: https://uxdesign.cc/samsungs-send-sos-messages-is-flawed-43e6a633fe4