# How to create a big panic button on the home screen that, when touched, makes a phone call to a specific person?

Tags: accessibility

As an elderly is going to use the smartphone, and has difficulty using technology, I would like to create a big panic button on the home screen for her, in order that she can immediately make a phone call to a specific person when touch it, without doing any more thing, only touching the panic button.

It is desirable that, when the smartphone is seemingly off (I don't know the proper name. Is it "standby"?), if the user presses the power button once, the panic button will appear and can be used, without the necessity to unlock the smartphone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A wrongly 'I need help' text was sent from google maps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/214163/a-wrongly-i-need-help-text-was-sent-from-google-maps)

Comment: No. The suggestion of power 5x times, however, was good. The challenge is to enable it.

Comment: search for [emergency sos](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+send+SOS+messages+on+android) it is built-in feature